# Free a structure.... I'm not sure if I do it right

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure, free

My program manage a linked list of structure.

Here is my struc:

```
typedef struct wagon wagon;
typedef struct wagon{
    wagon *next;
    marchandise_ptr *liste;
    double volume_courant;
}train_ptr;
```

Where wagon *next is a pointer to the next "cell" of my linked list, marchandise_ptr *list is a pointer to another linked list. To free my strucure, I've proceed as followed:

In int main():

```
train_ptr *train=creer_un_train(...)//so train is the beginning of my linked list
liberer_train(&train);
```

My functions are:

Creates a "wagon"

```
wagon *creer_wagon(marchandise_ptr *liste,double volume_courant){ //it creates a wagon
    assert(volume_courant>=0);
    wagon *wag=malloc(sizeof(wagon));
    if(wag==NULL)
        return NULL;
    wag->next=NULL;
    wag->volume_courant=volume_courant;
    wag->liste=liste;
    return wag;
}
```

Add the created "wagon" at the end of my chained list:

```
train_ptr *ajouter_wagon_a_la_fin_du_train(train_ptr *train,double volume_courant, marchandise_ptr *liste){
    wagon *wag=creer_wagon(liste,volume_courant);
    if(wag==NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(train==NULL)
        train=wag;
    else{
        train_ptr *wag_current=train;
        while(wag_current->next!=NULL)
            wag_current=wag_current->next;
        wag_current->next=wag;
        }
    return train;
}
```

Creates a train:

```
train_ptr *creer_un_train(unsigned int nombre_de_wagons,marchandise_ptr *liste){
    assert(nombre_de_wagons>=0);
    int i;
    train_ptr *train=NULL;

    for(i=0;i<nombre_de_wagons;i++){
        train=ajouter_wagon_a_la_fin_du_train(train,rand()%10,liste);
        if(train==NULL)
            return NULL;
        }
    return train;
}
```

Free a train:

```
void liberer_train(train_ptr **train){
    train_ptr *p_current = *train;
    while(p_current!=NULL){
                *train = p_current->next;
                p_current->next=NULL;
                free(p_current->liste);
                free(p_current);
                p_current = *train;
    }
}
```

P.S.: liste is a pointer to the beginnig of a linked list:

```
typedef struct marchandise marchandise;
typedef struct marchandise{
    double volume;
    double volume_total;
    char nom;
    marchandise *suivant;
}marchandise_ptr;
```

Thanks for your attention! (and sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.... :D )

Comment: You can use valgrind to search for memory leaks.

Comment: I don't see what is `liste`? Where is it pointing to

Comment: Liste is pointing to the biginning of another linked list (also componed of structures)

Comment: if `p_current->liste` is another linked list, the `free(p_current->liste)` will only free the root node, and you have a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the mistake, thanks ;)

Comment: Also, it makes no sense to do `p_current->next = NULL;` because after you `free` `p_current` trying to access `next` will be undefined behavior anyway. And why do you pass a `train_ptr **`.

Comment: @iharob: Passing a `train_ptr **` allows `*train = 0;` at the end of the function so the pointer in the calling code is nullified — though the code does not actually do that.  It reduces the number of dangling pointers by one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's exactly my point, but his usage is not compliant with this idea, so why did he do that then?

Comment: You say you didn't `malloc` the liste. What is it then? Is it a reference into memory owned by someone else? Can two wagons point to the same liste? Did you obtain it via a "constructor" function, e.g. `liste_new()`?

Comment: @RominTomasetti and calling your type `train_ptr` is very confusing...

Comment: Note that: `typedef struct wagon { wagon *next; marchandise_ptr *liste; double volume_courant; } train_ptr;` is using a type, `wagon` that is unrelated to `struct wagon` because this is tagged C and not C++. If you are compiling with a C compiler, you need `struct wagon *next;` in the structure body. Also, it is usually sensible (IMNSHO) to use the same name for the tag and the type, or very closely related names for the tag and type names. That is `typedef struct X { … } X;` makes sense; some people use `typedef struct xyz_s { … } xyz_t;`. But `wagon` and `train_ptr` are not closely related.

Comment: I see you've updated the question to address my observation about the plain type name `wagon` — thanks.  But why have two type names for `struct wagon`?

Comment: Because my chained list represent a train: train_ptr *train points on the first cell of my chained list and in my source code, I use `wagon` to initialize a new cell of my linked list "train" so that the code is more "understandable" by a human ;)

Answer (score 1):

From your `creer_wagon` function, it doesn't seem like the `liste` should be freed by the `liberer_train` function, because it's not allocated by the `creer_wagon` function.

Following that logic, the function where you do the call to `creer_wagon` should be responsible for the `liste` member, because you will have a valid pointer to it in the scope of the caller function, and you risk a double `free` of the `liste` member.

If each `train` needs only to have a refrence to a `liste` but doesn't need to modify it you could define your struct like this

```
typedef struct wagon{
    wagon *next;
    const marchandise_ptr *liste;
    double volume_courant;
}train_ptr;
```

this will prevent accidentally trying to modify or `free` the `liste` member.

This design makes sense if many trains could point to the same `liste`, though it increases the responsabilities of the `struct wagon` users, because they should take care of the memory management for the `liste` member. If this is the case, I double recommend the `const` qualifier.

In my opinion this is a valid way of reasoning regardles of whether `liste` was allocated by you or not.

I suggest you fix the `liberer_train` function like this

```
void liberer_train(train_ptr **train) {
    train_ptr *p_current = *train;
    train_ptr *suivant   = NULL;
    while (p_current != NULL) {
        suivant = p_current->next;
        free(p_current);        
        p_current = suivant;
    }
    /* make the pointer NULL, so it's not a dangling pointer in the caller function anymore. */
    *train = NULL; 
}
```

and also, i suggest you change

```
typedef struct wagon train_ptr;
```

to

```
typedef struct wagon *train_ptr;
```

or

```
typedef struct wagon train;
```

for example, because the suffix `_ptr` makes one thinkg that in `train_ptr x;`  `x` is a pointer, while it's not.